# How to output Cinebench CMD logs to file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, benchmarking

I am currently trying to make a batch file to run a simple Cinebench benchmark on the CPU and then output the results. I can make it run the tests and output into the command prompt window, but I'm not sure how to capture this output an put it into a file.

Here is a copy from my CLI trying to run my current command. I shortened the output for clarity, as without it the output is extremely long. All of the "Loading" lines show no signs of error other than the first module, which to my knowledge is not critical to running the benchmarks, as the app can run, the benchmarks will complete, and the app can create its own report files. The folder is also empty on a fresh install, so I don't know its purpose.

Anyway, here's my command with following output:

```
H:\Cinebench>start /b /wait "parentconsole" Cinebench.exe g_CinebenchAllTests=true g_CinebenchMinimumTestDuration=1 > "C:\Test Results\CPUBench.txt"
Application start      : 10/08/21 at 14:53:13
Executable             : 64 Bit
Version / Build        : 23.200 / RBBenchmark330542
Debugger               : not available
Memory model           : release
Startup path           : file:///H:/Cinebench
Application path       : file:///H:/Cinebench/Cinebench.exe
Application executable : file:///H:/Cinebench/Cinebench.exe
Resource path          : file:///H:/Cinebench/resource
Module path(s)         : file:///H:/Cinebench/corelibs; file:///H:/Cinebench/plugins; file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Maxon/Cinebench_12266647/plugins
Temporary path         : file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp
Prefs path             : file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Maxon/Cinebench_12266647
Global Prefs path      : file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Maxon
OS version             : Windows 10, 64 Bit, Professional Edition (build 19043)
OS languages           : {en-US}
App languages          : {en-US}
Startup language       : en-US
Processor              : 2(4)x Intel Core i7-6600U CPU
Computer name          : DESKTOP-PQ3K0NB
Unique OS identifier   : 5tlz3MT11Ngrk5dFHCArOnSZxjCSf8cwGtkSRPm1Vc0= [uefi]
Thread Count           : 4
CPU Speed (MHz)        : 2810.000
Application Type       : Modular
Command line arguments : "g_CinebenchAllTests=true" "g_CinebenchMinimumTestDuration=1"

Module path file:///H:/Cinebench/plugins couldn't be found
Loading file:///H:/Cinebench/corelibs/asset.module.xdl64 with module(s) net.maxon.asset
... Loading files continues for some time ...
Loading file:///H:/Cinebench/corelibs/xtensions.xdl64 with module(s) net.maxon.c4d.xtensions
CINEBENCH started
Drawport API initialized
    Framework        : OpenGL
    Vendor           : Intel (INTELCORP)
    Renderer         : Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
    Framework version: 4.6.0 - Build 27.20.100.8681
    Driver version   : 27.20.100.8681
CINEBENCH AUTORUN
Please wait until all tests are done!

Running Multiple CPU Render Test...
Minimum test duration: 1000.0 ms seconds.
Rendering...
Finalizing for 141.0 ms
Finalizing for 1156.8 ms
Finalizing for 2187.4 ms
Finalizing for 3218.4 ms
Finalizing for 4249.4 ms
Finalizing for 5280.4 ms
Finalizing for 6311.4 ms
Finalizing for 7342.4 ms
Finalizing for 8373.4 ms
Finalizing for 9404.6 ms
Finalizing for 10435.4 ms
... This continues for some time ...
Finalizing for 395165.4 ms
Values: {2002.863} -> Avg/Deviation: 2002.863/0.000
CB 2002.86 (0.00)

Running Single CPU Render Test...
Minimum test duration: 1000.0 ms seconds.
Rendering...
Finalizing for 149.9 ms
Finalizing for 1180.9 ms
Finalizing for 2211.9 ms
Finalizing for 3242.9 ms
Finalizing for 4273.9 ms
Finalizing for 5305.0 ms
Finalizing for 6336.0 ms
Finalizing for 7367.0 ms
Finalizing for 8398.0 ms
Finalizing for 9429.0 ms
Finalizing for 10460.0 ms
Finalizing for 11490.9 ms
Finalizing for 12522.0 ms
... This continues for some time ...
Finalizing for 894210.8 ms
Values: {886.231} -> Avg/Deviation: 886.231/0.000
CB 886.23 (0.00)
```

I want this output to go into a file with the path "C:\Test Results\CPUBench.txt". I would also like to filter out all lines with "Finalizing" and "Loading", as these aren't relevant information for me. I would also like to completely overwrite the file if at all possible.

I have some basic UNIX/LINUX experience, but Windows CLI is relatively unknown to me. My go-to standard output redirection symbol '>' doesn't seem to be working for this task. I can make it a batch file myself after I have the command working, so I really just need a way for this one command to do what I want.

Comment: If the initial attempt of `>filename` resulted in an empty file with the text being displayed on the screen, it's likely that the program outputs to stderr for some reason. Try `start /b /wait "parentconsole" Cinebench.exe g_CinebenchAllTests=true g_CinebenchMinimumTestDuration=1 2>"C:\Test Results\CPUBench.txt"` instead. (I don't have the program installed so I can't test this, and I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't write guesses as answers.) Barring that, I'd be amazed if a benchmarking software _didn't_ contain some flag for specifying an output file.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use the `START` command.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this functionality as well. Cinebench must be launched with `start` and its own console in order to see its stdout but `start` doesn't play well with stdout redirection. Here's what I wrote after some experimentation:

```
echo Starting Cinebench loop... > r23_output.txt
for /L %%i IN (1,1,5) do (
  echo Cinebench Run # %%i >> r23_output.txt
  start /b /wait "r23 window" cmd.exe /C "C:\miscprogs\R23\Cinebench.exe g_CinebenchCpuXTest=true g_CinebenchCpu1Test=false g_CinebenchMinimumTestDuration=1 >> r23_output.txt"
)
findstr /b "CB" r23_output.txt > r23_results.txt
```

This performs 5 runs of Cinebench R23's multi-core test, with no minimum duration per test. The full log output is stored in `r23_output.txt`; the actual test results are extracted from the full log and stored in `r23_results.txt`. On my system I've chosen to put the Cinebench executable in `c:\miscprogs\R23` - change to whatever path you've placed it in. If you'd like to run the single-core test then change `g_CinebenchCpu1Test=` to true.

I've created a GitHub repository to maintain a version of this batch file:

https://github.com/horshack-dpreview/CinebenchBatch